# Where is engine oil cap on Mazda 626?

Tags: oil-change, mazda

There is a front cap but it does not say engine oil. When I open it, i can see engine parts in it. I just want to pour in more oil? Is it somewhere hidden, or this is it?

I understand there are 2 types of oil, engine oil and transmission oil. What I am looking at looks like transmission oil cap.

Comment: can you post a photo?Have you checked the owners manual?Generally the cap will have an image of an oilcan on it.

Comment: That's right it has had oil can on it. But I found the manual anyhow and that helped. Posted my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found an online document and it solved the problem. The cap on top of the engine is the motor oil

http://www.mazdausa.com/MusaWeb/pdf/quicktips/01Mazda626QT.pdf